# Как посчитать количество строк кода в проекте?

Tags: phpstorm

С помощью PHPStorm желательно. Есть в нём такая функция?
И в конкретной папке проекта неплохо бы знать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В базовом функционале такой возможности нет. Установите из официального репозитория [плагин Statistic](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4509-statistic). Его настройки в File->Settings->Tools->Statistic.

Кнопка внизу слева, по нажатию можно получить примерно такой вывод на экран:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перед установкой плагина обязательно требуется Java 1.8 https://java.com/ru/download/